# Multistore: removing __store when stores on different domain

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, language

we have a stor with multiple languages. They are on different domains.

In our endeavour to clean the URL, we want to remove `__store` and `__from_store`

**step 1. __from_store is removed like so**

```
Change the your page/switch/languages.phtml file
replace all code: $_lang->getCurrentUrl()
with $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false)
```

UPDATE `$_lang->getCurrentUrl(false)` also breaks th store id lookup. Hence the store specific URL is not returned. So adding false is NOT the solution.

**step 2. Remove __store**

Option 1. When all the stores are on the same domain. Go to `System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL Options` and set the '`Add Shop Code to URLs`' option to `Yes`

---

**My question:** all stores are on a different domain. How do I now remove the `__store` element in our url? The solution under step 2 does of course not work.

thx ;P